# angular.merge not working correctly for associative arrays (Objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS code that pulls data from a DB via a backend HTTP request:

```
    // Get the list of functions and associated metrics
    $http.get("/BackEnd/Queries/GetFunctionListWithMetrics.php?BuildID=" + $scope.Build.ID + "&ClassID=" + $scope.Class.ID)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            // Save the data
            //$scope.functionlist = data;
            angular.merge($scope.functionlist, data);

            // We've finished loading
            $scope.isLoading = false;
        })
```

"data" is an associative array where the key is a number (Typically something like "718214").

Originally my code had the line "$scope.functionlist = data;" (Currently shown commented out) and everything worked fine. I then switched to using the angular.merge line instead (As I was going to fire off several different http requests and I wanted the results all to merge into the same $scope.functionlist object).

From a functionality point of view this worked fine. My page continued to show the data correctly and my multiple HTTP requests could gather the data and merge it together without any timing\ordering concerns.

However for some reason my page started running very slowly. There were no errors shown in the console.

Eventually I worked out what the problem was by adding the following 2 lines and comparing the contentns of functionlist and functionlist2:

```
$scope.functionlist2 = data;
angular.merge($scope.functionlist, data);
```

I realised that whilst functionlist2 contained my associative array with about 10 keys, the functionlist version contained an array of 718214 elements!!!

It appears that angular.merge incorrectly interpreted the numeric key of data as an array index.

I've not seen anything about this in the angular documentation or on the web.

Is this a known issue? And is there another way to achieve the correct result (i.e. without 700+k array elements)?

Thanks in advance.

*Edit*

Ah, Javascript doesn't support associative arrays, only objects. Hmmm, I'm still not sure how to achieve what I need though.

Comment: [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I worked it out in the end and it was actually very simple.

Of course Javascript doesn't actually support associative arrays, just numerically indexed array and objects, so what I actually had was an object.

So in the end all I had to do was initialise $scope.functionlist like this:

```
$scope.functionlist = {};
```

instead of how I had been doing it (As an array) like this:

```
$scope.functionlist = [];
```

Now it's all working perfectly.